# Subscript: how to randomly select items and change their values in numpy by their subscript

Tags: python, list, numpy, for-loop

I got some problems in randomly change values in numpy by their array's subscript.
e.g.  I have 200 students in a grade.  I would like Choose 12 of them  by randomly selecting to join a science knowledge competition. And 3 of them in the selected 12 students will get prize.
code  i wrote had snytax error as follows :

```
import numpy as np
    import random
    N = 200
    U = np.zeros([N])  # means 200 students(U(0),U(1),...U(199)),U=0 means no prize
    alist = random.sample(range(0,N),12) #Choose 12 students by through 'U' subcript[0-200)
    b = random.sample((alist),3) #Choose 3 by alist's values (3 of different subscripts in U) 
    for i in range(b):
       U(i)=1 # index b values in 'U' subcript and change these item values into 1.1=got prize

can't assign to function call
```

btw,next i would to do is if in a year i have four times competition like above said ，how many students in a grade will get prize(students who got prize in former will not be choosed again).

Comment: Subscripts – list indexes – are [written with square brackets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
list=[x for x in range(1,200)]
winner1=12
finalwinners=3
pick1=[]
for x in range(winner1):
    pick1.append(random.choices(list))
print(pick1)
for x in range(finalwinners):
    print(random.choices(pick1))
```

Comment: Thanks melihuyelik! thanks u answering.I have coeded from your answer ,the output was`[[40], [123], [182], [8], [189], [192], [19], [114], [128], [47], [42], [53]]
[[189]]
[[19]]
[[19]]`  the finalwinner got duplicate,had two [19].btw i m not only just choose them but also want change these values in numpy.  i hope to mark them as values to be'1' them sum(s) .so i could get how many students get prize by 1st time,2nd time,3rd ,4th time.

Comment: for x in range(finalwinners):
    k=random.choices(pick1)
    prize_winner.append(k)
    if k in list:
        k=random.choices(pick1)

    else:
        print(f'Winner {x+1}', prize_winner[x])    ----- this could be usefull for repetaing pics. u can store final result in a txt then load and search student names in winner.txt

Comment: !!!Appreciate for u kind and patient teaching !

Comment: @empty: If melihuyelik’s answer resolved your question and was useful, be sure to mark it as the accepted answer and consider upvoting it. That’s how we recognize and reward contributor’s who take time to answer questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: how to mark it as acceptable?